# Trace not working in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, trace

I have an ASP.NET application that I'm trying to write some logging info on. To do this, I wanted to use tracing. I believe I have it setup properly. In my web.config file, I have:

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp"
                extension=".cs"
                compilerOptions="/d:TRACE"
                type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="1" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener"  type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\\logs\\mylog.log" />
        <remove name="default"/>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

In my code, I have the following:

```
Trace.WriteLine("Test Trace");
Trace.Flush();
```

However, mylog.log never gets created. What am I doing wrong? Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the app has the necessary security rights and permissions to access that folder/file.  Also ensure the folder exists.

I believe in the interests of keeping an app running in times of trouble, if you misconfigure a trace listener like this the app will continue without error.

(Of course, it could also be that your logging code is never reached)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you enabled tracing:

```
<trace enabled="true" ...
```